# What is the correct Taylor expansion of exponentiated operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, vector-analysis, matrix-exponential

I am trying to derive the following result from [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/supplemental/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.020405/Supplement.pdf) (Equation S3):$$e^{-ik_z\hat{z}}\hat{\rho}e^{+ik_z\hat{z}} - \hat{\rho} \approx k_z^2[\hat{z},[\hat{z}, \hat{\rho}]]$$with operators $\rho, z$.

The authors state the expansion below is sufficient to arrive at the result. The details in the paper are not relevant to understand the problem, it suffices to know that we deal with operators.

> The exponential operators can be expanded to the lowest order in the one-dimensional coordinate z in the present case

I then did the expansion by using the series expansion of the exponential function ($\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{(ik)^n}{n!}z^n$) $$e^{ik_z\hat{z}} \approx \mathbb{I} + ik_z\hat{z}$$ which got me
$$e^{-ik_z\hat{z}}\hat{\rho}e^{+ik_z\hat{z}} - \hat{\rho} \approx k_z^2z\rho z + i_kz[z, \rho]$$Evidently, this is not the result from the paper. I also checked the [BCH-formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) and found that my result would be correct if $[z, \rho]$ would commute with either $\rho$ or $z$. This can't be the case here as otherwise, the first expression would be zero.

Where is my mistake?

**EDIT**

I am aware that the matrix exponential only holds for square matrices, so it is questionable if I can apply the series expansion as I did above. If this is indeed the mistake, *what* would be the correct expansion?

Comment: Is it $[\hat z, [\hat z, \hat\rho]]$? (You are missing a comma?)

Comment: @Gary Fixed it, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The paper says to expand in $x$, not $\hat{z}$. Could this be the source of the discrepancy?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Ah no this is simply because I used a different name, I will fix the confusion

Comment: Should it be $k^2[z[z,\rho]]$? Otherwise I'm not sure where the $k$s disappear to.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, also that is true, my bad, fixed it.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521918/is-there-an-analogue-extension-of-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula-for-the-conju) gives a formula for the expansion of the exponential, but suggests the answer would be $-ik[z,\rho]-k^2[z,[z,\rho]]/2 + ...$. Attempting the BCH expansion directly gives something similar, though I could have made an algebra error. Not sure where the commutator goes.

Comment: Perhaps the term linear in $k$ vanishes because of the parity of the integrand? (just a guess I have no context other than looking at S3)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going up to second order in $k$, your exponential expansion also needs to be second order. This gives
\begin{multline}
e^{-ikz}\rho e^{ikz} = \left(\mathbb I -ikz -\frac{k^2z^2}{2} + ...\right)\rho\left(\mathbb I +ikz -\frac{k^2z^2}{2} + ...\right) \\= \rho-ikz\rho+ik\rho z + \frac{k^2}{2}\left(z^2\rho -2z\rho z + \rho z^2\right)+ ...
 = \rho - ik[z,\rho]+\frac{k^2}{2}[z,[z,\rho]] + ...,
\end{multline}
in agreement with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521918/is-there-an-analogue-extension-of-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula-for-the-conju). So we should get
$$
e^{-ikz}\rho e^{ikz} -\rho \approx -ik[z,\rho] + \frac{k^2}{2}[z,[z,\rho]].
$$
I'm not sure where the commutator term goes. Perhaps there's something in the paper that justifies neglecting it?